# Kafka Console Producer sending message failed

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to ask anyone face before this kind of stuation?
Few days ago the kafka is able to work properly but today it starting having problem. The console producer is unable to send message and receive by console consumer. After few seconds it prompt :

`" ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 11 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. "`

Anyone can help? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see this if the broker you are bootstrapping from is not reachable. Try to telnet to the host and port you are trying to access from the producer. If that communication is OK, turn on debug logging by locating the tools-log4j.properties and changing the warn level to debug.